# Remove a part of a log in Loki

Tags: nginx, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have installed Grafana, Loki, Promtail and Prometheus with the [`grafana/loki-stack`](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/loki-stack).

I also have Nginx set up with the [Nginx helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx).

Promtail is ingesting logs fine into Loki, but I want to customise the way my logs look. Specifically I want to remove a part of the log because it creates errors when trying to parse it with either `logfmt` or `json` (`Error: LogfmtParserErr` and `Error: JsonParserErr` respectively).

The logs look like this:

```
2022-02-21T13:41:53.155640208Z stdout F timestamp=2022-02-21T13:41:53+00:00 http_request_method=POST http_response_status_code=200 http_response_time=0.001 http_version=HTTP/2.0 http_request_body_bytes=0 http_request_bytes=63
```

and I want to remove the part where it says `stdout F` so the log will look like this:

```
2022-02-21T13:41:53.155640208Z timestamp=2022-02-21T13:41:53+00:00 http_request_method=POST http_response_status_code=200 http_response_time=0.001 http_version=HTTP/2.0 http_request_body_bytes=0 http_request_bytes=63
```

I have figured out that on the ingestion side it could be something with Promtail, but ist it also possible to make a LogQL query in Loki to just replace that string? And how would one set up the Promtail configuration for the wanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promtail should be configured to replace the string with the [`replace` stage](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/replace/).

Here is a sample config that removes the `stdout F` part of the log for all logs coming from the namespace *ingress*.

```yaml
promtail:
  enabled: true
  pipelineStages:
  - docker: {}
  - match:
      selector: '{namespace="ingress"}'
      stages:
      - replace:
          expression: "(stdout F)"
          replace: ""
```

Specifically this example works for the `grafana/loki-stack` chart.

Answer (score 7):

According to the docs a better approach is to enable the cri pipeline stage instead of the docker one. Assuming that you are ingesting logs from a recent kubernetes installation that uses CRI.

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/configuration/#cri